# Old versions of documents go to recycling bin when documents sent to Record Center

Tags: records-center, recycle-bin

I have a record center implemented implemented in my SharePoint 2010 system. I have discovered that when documents get sent to the record center old versions of the sent documents end up in the recycling bin. This is all good and well except its pointless having these old versions in the recycling bin because you can't restore them. All they do is take up space. Does anyone know if there is a way to stop old versions going to the recycling bin when documents get sent to Record Center?